# how to make dynamic forms

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

i want to save data (result) but three fields with the same name. when one is enabled others are disabled. it works for me. but the problem is that when i edit it from grid, two ,, added with values......... [in extjs 4 mvc]

### here is my view

```
Ext.define('Ext4Example.view.employee.Education' ,{
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
alias : 'widget.education',
modal:true,
autoShow: true,
bodyPadding: 5,

initComponent: function () {

this.items = [
            {
            xtype: 'form',
            id:'form',
            bodyStyle: {
                        background: 'none',
                        padding: '10px',
                        border: '0'
                       },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                    items: [                

                        {
                            xtype: 'combobox',
                            fieldLabel: 'Result Type',
                            emptyText:'Select Result Type',
                            displayField:'type',
                            valueField:'id',
                            store: 'TypeStocks',
                            name: 'type',
                            id:'type',
                            width: 265,                                
                            allowBlank:false,
                            anchor:'95%',
                            listeners : {
                                'select': {
                                    fn: function (combo, value) {
                                    var value=combo.getValue();
                                    if(value =='1'){
                                    Ext.getCmp('cgpa').hide();
                                    Ext.getCmp('jak').hide();
                                    Ext.getCmp('sc').hide(); 
                                    Ext.getCmp('range').hide();
                                    Ext.getCmp('range').disable();
                                    Ext.getCmp('cgpa').disable();
                                    Ext.getCmp('division').enable();
                                    Ext.getCmp('division').show();
                                      }
                                    else if(value =='2'){
                                    Ext.getCmp('division').disable();
                                    Ext.getCmp('division').hide();
                                    Ext.getCmp('cgpa').enable();
                                    Ext.getCmp('cgpa').show(); 
                                    Ext.getCmp('jak').show(); 
                                    Ext.getCmp('sc').show(); 
                                    Ext.getCmp('range').enable();
                                          Ext.getCmp('range').show();                                                                              
                                    }
                                  }
                              }
                           }
                        },
                        {
                            xtype:'combobox',
                            fieldLabel: 'Division',
                            name: 'result',
                            emptyText:'Select Result',                            
                            store: Division,
                            id:'division',
                            width: 265,
                            anchor:'95%',
                            allowBlank:false
                        },
                        {
                        xtype:'fieldcontainer',
                        layout: 'hbox',
                        items:[  
                          {
                            xtype:'label',
                            text:'Score',
                            hidden: true,
                            id:'sc'
                           },
                         {
                            xtype:'textfield',
                            name: 'result',
                            hidden: true,
                            width: 68,
                            margin:'0 0 0 75',
                            id:'cgpa',
                            anchor:'95%',
                            emptyText:'Score',
                            vtype : 'radius',
                            allowBlank:false
                        },
                        {
                            xtype:'textfield',
                            name: 'result',
                            hidden: true,
                            width: 68,
                            margin:'0 0 0 75',
                            id:'gpa',
                            anchor:'95%',
                            emptyText:'Score',
                            vtype : 'radiuss',
                            allowBlank:false
                        },
                           {
                           xtype:'label',
                           text:'of',
                           hidden: true,
                           margin:'0 5 0 5',
                           id:'jak'
                           },
                        {
                            xtype: 'combobox',
                            emptyText:'Range',
                            store: range,
                            name: 'range',
                            id: 'range',
                            margin:'0 5 0 5',
                            width: 65,
                            hidden: true,
                            anchor:'95%',
                            allowBlank:false,
                            listeners : {
                                'select': {
                                    fn: function (combo, value) {
                                    var value=combo.getValue();
                                 if(value =='5.00'){ 
                                    Ext.getCmp('outOf').setValue(1);
                                    Ext.getCmp('cgpa').enable();
                                    Ext.getCmp('cgpa').show();
                                    Ext.getCmp('gpa').setValue('');
                                    Ext.getCmp('gpa').disable();
                                    Ext.getCmp('gpa').hide();
                                  }
                                  else if(value =='4.00'){
                                    Ext.getCmp('outOf').setValue(0);
                                    Ext.getCmp('gpa').enable();
                                    Ext.getCmp('gpa').show();
                                    Ext.getCmp('cgpa').setValue('');
                                    Ext.getCmp('cgpa').disable();
                                    Ext.getCmp('cgpa').hide();                                       
                                    }          
                               }
                            }
                          }
                        }]                            
                        },


                        {
                     xtype: 'button',
                     text: 'SAVE',                                                   
                     iconCls: 'savee',
                     handler: function () {                                  
                            var form = this.up('form').getForm(),
                            values = form.getValues(); 

                      var education = Ext.create('Ext4Example.model.EducationModel',values);
                      // if (form.isValid()) {  
                          education.save({
                          success: function(education) {
                              var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.get('EducationStocks');
                              store = !store ? Ext.create("EducationStocks") : store;                                   
                              store.load();

                          },
                          failure: function(education){                                 
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', 'Data already exits');
                          }

                           });
                      //  }

                    }
                },
                {
                     xtype: 'button',
                     text: 'Cancel',
                     margin:'0 0 0 5',
                     scope: this,
                     handler: this.close
                }]  
         }]

}];
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

```
          ---------------
```

### model

```
Ext.define('Ext4Example.model.EducationModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
idProperty: 'id',
fields: [                   
    {name: 'result', mapping:'result', type: 'string'} ,
    {name: 'outOf', mapping:'outOf', type: 'int'} 

],
 proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    noCache: false,
    api: {
        create  : '${createLink(controller:'education', action: 'create')}'
    },
    actionMethods: {
        create : 'POST'            
    },        
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        totalProperty   : 'total',
        successProperty : 'success',
        messageProperty : 'message',
        implicitIncludes: true
    },
    writer: {
      type: 'json',
      root: 'data',
      writeAllFields: true 
    },
    simpleSortMode: true
},
belongsTo: [{model:'Ext4Example.model.ExamModel', name:'exams'}]
```

});

Comment: Question unclear. What does "i edit it from grid, two ,, added with values......... [in extjs 4 mvc]" mean?

Comment: well, when i add respective values in the form , i display it into the grid. by double clicking row of the grid i open a new window to edit those entries. after editing i find the respective grid cell with extra two commas(,,) included with the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two of more fields have the same name, when the form is submitted, the fields with the same name are clubbed together into an array and then submitted. So, if you check the parameter submitted to the server, they will be :

```
type : typeValue
result : [resultFromCombo, resultFromTextField1, resultFromTextField2]
range : rangeValue
```

So in the server, I think you are directly converting the result array into a string and saving it. On converting the result array to a string it will convert to `resultFromCombo, resultFromTextField1, resultFromTextField2`. Hence you are getting the 2 commas in your grid.

Comment: Please post a solution if this wasn't it. Help the community.